# Making firebase return a sorted response

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database on Firebase. I am trying to make it so that, when users type in a value, they get 10 nearest suggestions back. This is my query so far:

```
<textarea className='addFriendTextArea' onChange={handleChange} placeholder='Dodaj znajomego'/>

handleChange = async (e) => {
    const {value} = e.target;
    firebase
        .database()
        .ref('Users')
        .orderByChild('nickname')
        .startAt(value)
        .limitToFirst(10)
        .once('value')
        .then(r => arrayFromObject(r.val()))
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
};
```

This almost works. The problem is that if I type in, for example, iron, I get this:

[image]

And if I type in, for example, brunonbane3, this is what I get:

[image]

So they're not sorted. I know I could probably sort them using my front end JavaScript, but is there a way to sort it using Firebase?

Also shouldn't typing in the exact nick, like for example iron, return only one record? There is no "iron2" type account. What's going on here?

Comment: `.startAt(value).limitToFirst(10)`, you're fetching (up to) 10 records starting at the matching record from the sorted set.

Comment: Yes, but it's not matching precisely the entered value. Why is that?

Comment: It's doing a string comparison on the values. searching for `iron2` would start at the first value that either matched the value or came after the search phrase. From your example you'd get the last 9 values from the iron example plus the next one in the sorted list.

Comment: Ok I guess it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: What does `arrayFromObject` do?

Comment: Forgot to take it out. It's a custom method that turns the returned object into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. It essentially contains three pieces of information: the key of each matching child, the value of each matching child, and the order of the matching child nodes.

When you call `r.val()` you're converting the above to a single JSON object, which only has place for the keys and the values. At this point you lose the order between the results. To maintain the order, make sure to loop over the results with the built-in `DataSnapshot.forEach()` method:

```
.then(snapshot => {
  var result = [];
  snapshot.forEach(child => {
    result.push(child.val());
  })
  return result;
})
```